# Error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException with .xlsx file

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, xlsx

I have a sheet,it includes: number,name,pass,access,result. I want get name,pass,result to testweb, I try writing it but i get this error  :

```
String user[],pass[],result[];
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(pathFile));
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
workbook.close();
if (sheet != null) {
int rowindex =0;
for(Row row : sheet) {
   for(Cell cell:row){
      int i=cell.getColumnIndex();
      if(i==1) user[rowindex]=cell.toString();
      if(i==2) pass[rowindex]=cell.toString();
      if(i==4) result[rowindex]=cell.toString();
      }
      rowindex++;
  }
} else {
    System.out.println("Sheet was not found");
  }
```

Comment: Please provide all the code involved and the stack trace

Comment: Also, if you're using Apache POI, you should be using `XSSFWorkbook`

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot of details in your question but based on the code you have I'm guessing your doing something like this

```
 FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(file));
 Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
 Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
```

My guess is your sheet is NULL. So you need to put some guard code in checking to make sure you have a valid sheet.

Something like this

```
 if (sheet != null) {
    int n = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    // Do the rest of you code
} else {
    System.out.println("Sheet was not found Check to make sure file was read and sheet was access properly.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it worked

```
   if (sheet != null) {  
          rowNum=sheet.getLastRowNum()+1; //getlastrow() return index last row
          String username[]=new String[rowNum];
          int index=0;
          Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
                while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                        Row row = rowIterator.next();
                        Iterator <Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                        index++;
                           while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                               Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                               if(cell.getColumnIndex()==1) 
                               username[index]=cell.toString();
                            }
                   }

     } else {
        System.out.println(" Sheet was not found ");
     }
```